# useState doesn't change simple state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to set height of 'tbody' dynamically. That is why I use 'useRef' which watch to position of the element 'tfoot', and check 'tfoot.offsetTop' and change 'heightTbody' until the tbody is positioned all the way to the bottom. In 'positionChecker' I compare window.height and 'tfoot.offsetTop'. In the condition i try to change the state but unsuccesseble 
What I do wrong? 
Thanks

**`Component.tsx`**

```
.....several imports

const Component= () => {
  const store = useContext(Context);
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
  const [heightTbody, setHeightTbody] = useState(650);
  const checkVisibilityFoot = useRef<HTMLTableSectionElement>(null);
  const [list, setList] = useState<ContentI[]>([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const temp = await store.getContent();
    setList(temp);
  };
  const resizeHolder = (e: UIEvent) => {
    const w = e.target as Window;
    if (!isNaN(w.innerHeight) && isFinite(w.innerHeight))
      positionChecker(w.innerHeight, checkVisibilityFoot.current?.offsetTop as number);
  };

  const positionChecker = (windHeight: number, checkVisFoot: number) => {
    if (windHeight < checkVisFoot) {
      setHeightTbody((prevState) => prevState - 1); // <-- here must be changed
      positionChecker(windHeight, checkVisibilityFoot.current?.offsetTop as number);
    }    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHolder);
  return (
 <table>
  <tbody style={{ height: heightTbody + 'px' }}>
     ......content
  </tbody>
  <tfoot ref={checkVisibilityFoot}></tfoot>
</table>

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch for changes, pass params to `useEffect` array.